# Detect when other user of site is typing

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

I have a chat script made entirely with PHP, MySQL and some JavaScripts.

In the chat window (which made from 2 frames), the 1st shows the user messages and the 2nd is the text typing area.

The frames are connected with the function `target`.

```
echo "< frame name=\"chatviewpage\" src=\"$chatviewurl\" scrolling=\"no\">";
echo "< frame name=\"chattextpage\" target=\"chatviewpage\" src=\"$chattexturl\" scrolling=\"no\">";
```

So when the user sends a message, it automatically shows up in the `chatview` frame. In the `chattextpage`, I already used the `onkeypress` function so that if the user hits "enter" the message will be sent.

Now, I want to add the function of letting user know when his buddy is typing a message. I found on a previous question the script I need, but I can't figure out how to integrate it.

The script is below:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
var timer = 0;
function reduceTimer(){
    timer = timer - 1;
    isTyping(true);
}
function isTyping(val){
    if(val == 'true'){
        document.getElementById('typing_on').innerHTML = "User is typing...";
    }else{

        if(timer <= 0){
            document.getElementById('typing_on').innerHTML = "No one is typing at the moment.";
        }else{
            setTimeout("reduceTimer();",500);
        }
    }
}
</script>
<label>
    <textarea onkeypress="isTyping('true'); timer=5;" onkeyup="isTyping('false')" name="textarea" id="textarea" cols="45" rows="5"></textarea>
</label>
<div id="typing_on">No one is typing at the moment.</div>
```

I hope it's well explained, could somebody help please?

Comment: Seems like you need some ajax to determine that.

Answer (score 0):

When a key is pressed:

1. Check if there's an existing timer
2. stop it if there is one
   start a timer.

When the timer expires, call the server method.

```
    var searchTimeout;
    document.getElementById('searchBox').onkeypress = function () {
        if (searchTimeout != undefined) clearTimeout(searchTimeout);
        searchTimeout = setTimeout(callServerScript, 250);
    };
    function callServerScript() {
        // your code here
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically what this is doing is setting a variable to true or false depending on whether or not the person is keying down or up:

```
    //setup before functions
var delay = (function(){
    var timer = 0;
    return function(callback, ms){
        clearTimeout (timer);
        timer = setTimeout(callback, ms);
    };
})();

$('textarea').on('change',function(){
   delay(function(){
      //make your server call here
   },2000);
});
```

Comment: actually , my textarea look's like this for more precision :

< textarea class="chattext" style="margin-bottom: 0px; margin-top: 0px;" onkeypress="if (event.keyCode == 13) {return blockSubmit();}" onkeyup="showCounter();" rows="3" name="txt_message" id="txt_message" maxlength="500" style="width: 300px; overflow: scroll;"></textarea >